# Crystal Report references missing in VB6

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

A client handed a Visual Basic 6 project to me, it uses Crystal Report. So when I run the project, an error message appeared.

[image]

I know that I don't have the crystal report dlls and ocx files. Can someone help me to make this project run? Or at least give me a link on where to download the missing files and the steps.

Comment: Scan you scroll across and let me know exactly what librarys it needs? I.e, 10 or 11?

Comment: You can see it from the reference window, the last two items marked as MISSING.

Comment: The active X designer runtime, can't see a version number :)

EDIT - Stupid me, I can see it now!

Comment: Both Crystal are 10.0

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get these dll's for free legally. You can still purchase Crystal Reports XI (not to be confused with version 2011) , which is the last version that is compatible with VB6.

[See the SAP store.](http://store.businessobjects.com/DRHM/store?Action=DisplayProductDetailsPage&SiteID=bobjamer&Locale=en_US&ThemeID=29254600&Env=BASE&productID=97983100&parentCategoryID=57065700&categoryID=57103400&_s_icmp=CG4CCB4CE)